# django accessing other apps variable

Tags: django

How can i get access to variables in other apps, like i have /posts/ /polls/ ...

if i want to get from /polls/ app access to specific variable, is it possible and how ?

when i just try accessing like `{{ poll.question }}` it doesn`t do anything
/blog/index.html

```
<div class="news">  
    {{ poll.question }}
</div>
```

/polls/index.html

```
{% extends "blog/index.html" %}
{% block poll %}
    {% if latest_poll_list %}
        <ul>
            {% for poll in latest_poll_list %}
                <li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' poll.id %}">{{ poll.question }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% else %}
        <p>No polls are available.</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done, but not in the template. It's done in the view function, and passed to the  template via the [context](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#playing-with-context-objects), and you import it like any other python module/variable.

```
# in posts.views
from polls.models import Poll

def index_view(request):
    context = {'latest_poll_list': Poll.objects.all()[:5]} # Or whatever...
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1):

there are a couple of ways to do it:

- pass the queryset to the context, in the render function. Or in the get_context_data() if you are using CBV
- Maybe there are multiple views where you want this poll list, so you could write a Mixin, if you are using CBV, that overrides the get_context_data to add the `latest_poll_list` var in the context. This should be easier to maintain.
- Or if almost all of your views need this poll list, you could write a context processor that will put your variable in ALL the templates,
- Or you could create your own template tag to display the list of polls

I'd choose the second one